# MS Sql Server, same column with a different row neighbors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need a little help on a SQL query. I could not get the result that I wanted.

```
ID  I10  H 10NS HNS CC  NSCC
0    1   1   1   1  14  14

1    0   1   0   1  6   2

1    0   2   0   2  12  2

1    0   3   0   3  17  4

1    0   3   0   3  18  4

1    0   3   0   3  19  4

1    0   3   0   3  20  4
```

What I want to have is one from each ID with highest CC

For example,

```
  ID I10 H  10NS HNS CC  NSCC
  0  1   1   1    1  14  14
  1  0   3   0    3  20  4
```

I tried with this code:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.name, a.i10 as[i-10-index], a.h as[h-index], 10ns as[i-10-index based on non-self-citation], a.hns as [h-index based on non-self-citation],
max(a.[Citation Count]), (a.[Non-Self-Citation Count])
FROM tbl_lpNumerical as a 
join tbl_lpAcademician as b
on a.ID= (b.ID-1)  
GROUP BY a.ID, b.name, a.i10, a.h, a.10ns, a.hns,
a.[Non-Self-Citation Count]
order by a.ID desc
```

However, I could not get the desired results.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your query seems to have nothing to do with your sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get all the row where not exist another row with an higher CC

```
SELECT n.*
FROM tbl_lpNumerical n
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'b'
                   FROM tbl_lpNumerical n2
                   WHERE n2.ID = n.ID
                   AND n2.CC > n.CC
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select a *single* row from each `ID` partition: the one with the *highest* `CC` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CC DESC) AS rn 
      FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If there can be multiple rows having the same `CC` max value and you want *all of them* selected, then you can replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`.

Comment: where should I put my table name?

Comment: @Elesmoth Ooops, sorry. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` for this.  Based on your *sample data*`, something like:

```
select sd.*
from (select sd.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by cc desc) as seqnum
      from sampledata sd
     ) sd
where seqnum = 1;
```

I have no idea what your query has to do with the sample data.  If it generates the data, then you can use a CTE:

```
with sampledata as (
      <some query here>
     )
select sd.*
from (select sd.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by cc desc) as seqnum
      from sampledata sd
     ) sd
where seqnum = 1;
```